# Python - list comprehension in this case is efficient?

Tags: python

The is the input "dirty" list in python

```
input_list = ['  \n  ','  data1\n ','   data2\n','  \n','data3\n'.....]
```

each list element contains either empty spaces with new line chars or data with newline chars

Cleaned it up using the below code..

```
cleaned_up_list = [data.strip() for data in input_list if data.strip()]
```

gives

```
  cleaned_up_list =   ['data1','data2','data3','data4'..]
```

Does python internally call `strip()` twice during the above list comprehension? or would i have to use a `for` loop iteration and `strip()` just once if i cared about efficiency?

```
for data in input_list
  clean_data = data.strip()
     if(clean_data):
         cleaned_up_list.append(clean_data)
```

Comment: You can find this out yourself, by writing a custom function that increments a counter and/or prints out each time it's called.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using your list comp strip *is* called twice, use a gen exp if you want to only call strip once and keep the comprehension:

```
input_list[:] = [x for x in (s.strip() for s in input_list) if x]
```

Input:

```
input_list = ['  \n  ','  data1\n ','   data2\n','  \n','data3\n']
```

Output:

```
 ['data1', 'data2', 'data3']
```

`input_list[:]` will change the original list which may or may not be what you want, if you actually want to create a new list just use `cleaned_up_list = ...`.

I always found using `itertools.imap` in python 2  and `map` in python 3 instead of the generator to be the most efficient for larger inputs:

```
from itertools import imap
input_list[:] = [x for x in imap(str.strip, input_list) if x]
```

Some timings with different approaches:

```
In [17]: input_list = [choice(input_list) for _ in range(1000000)]   

In [19]: timeit filter(None, imap(str.strip, input_list))
10 loops, best of 3: 115 ms per loop

In [20]: timeit list(ifilter(None,imap(str.strip,input_list)))
10 loops, best of 3: 110 ms per loop

In [21]: timeit [x for x in imap(str.strip,input_list) if x]
10 loops, best of 3: 125 ms per loop

In [22]: timeit [x for x in (s.strip() for s in input_list) if x]  
10 loops, best of 3: 145 ms per loop

In [23]: timeit [data.strip() for data in input_list if data.strip()]
10 loops, best of 3: 160 ms per loop

In [24]: %%timeit                                                
   ....:     cleaned_up_list = []
   ....:     for data in input_list:
   ....:          clean_data = data.strip()
   ....:          if clean_data:
   ....:              cleaned_up_list.append(clean_data)
   ....: 

10 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop

In [25]: 

In [25]: %%timeit                                                    
   ....:     cleaned_up_list = []
   ....:     append = cleaned_up_list.append
   ....:     for data in input_list:
   ....:          clean_data = data.strip()
   ....:          if clean_data:
   ....:              append(clean_data)
   ....: 

10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

The fastest approach is actually `itertools.ifilter` combined with `itertools.imap` closely followed by `filter`with `imap`.

Removing the need to reevaluate the function reference `list.append` each iteration is  more efficient, if you were stuck with a loop and wanted the most efficient approach then it is a viable alternative.

Comment: Is it lighter than calling `strip()` twice?

Comment: For a lot of data, yes, because you set up the comprehensions once, but the strip is called on every element in the list.

Comment: @clemtoy, I added some timings for various approaches, you can see that calling strip twice is the least efficient approach

Comment: Out of curiosity, why `input_list[:] = ...` instead of `input_list = `? I get the feeling the answer has something to do with the copying of memory, but symbols are hard to search for.

Comment: @PythonNut, it changes the original list/object.It can change the original list while  It keeps the speed of the list comp, the  alternative using a loop might be `for i, ele in enumerate(list);list[ind] = ele.strip()` if the OP did want to update the original list.

Comment: Any chance of adding a timeit comparison for `filter(None, imap(str.strip, input_list))`? On my machine it's about 40% slower than the list comprehension with `if`, but you never know.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham correct me if i'm wrong but would `input_list = ...` delete the list and create it over again and `input_list[:] = ... ` would modify index positions with new data and thus bit more memory efficient?

Comment: @wolfgang,  `input_list = ... would reassign the `name` `input_list`  to the new list and the old list would be gc'd but only if there were no other references, if you happened to have a reference to the old list anywhere you would end up with the two objects in memory.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks, I understand, but once overwritten, are'nt all references to the "old" input_list immediately lost?

Comment: @SteveJessop, that is actually on of the  the fastest solutions which makes sense,  I added a new set of tests  including both   `list(ifilter(None,imap(str.strip,input_list)))`  and `filter(None,imap(str.strip,input_list))`

Comment: @wolfgang. try `a = [1,2,3];b=a;a=[4, 5, 6]`, then print a and b and you will see the old list is still hanging around because b still holds a reference to it

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yep, definitely makes sense